# How can I get Jenkins to ignore Checkstyle failures

Tags: jenkins

Ok, I see in the Checkstyle and Jenkins documentation, that Jenkins will fail the build and not perform any more build steps after the checkstyle build step which has violations.  However, I would like Jenkins to continue on with the next build step - ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven to build your project, the easiest solution is to add this property in your Maven CLI:

```
mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We have not yet migrated to maven (that is the plan though).  Is there a quick workaround I can use in the meantime?

Comment: You are using Ant to build your project?

Comment: Just using the good old commandline for now to invoke checkstyle:  java -jar checkstyle.jar